# View call return the result x 2

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a view call in php:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM contact_numers_view";
 $result=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
 //conversion from array to string
 $separater = implode(",", $result);
```

on `echo $separater` I should get a number 100020 but instead of this I get it doubled like `100020, 100020`

Any hint about what is wrong?

The view is:

```
CREATE VIEW contact_numers_view AS
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts;
```

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump($result)` ?

Comment: please provide what is the result by printing the output for `$result`

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "101912" ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(6) "101912" }` that is the var_dump result. I don't understand why there are 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

see `http://in3.php.net/mysql_fetch_array`

Use `result_type` as `MYSQL_NUM`

In you code do as follows,

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM contact_numers_view";
 $result=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query), MYSQL_NUM);
 //conversion from array to string
 $separater = implode(",", $result);
```

And moreover mysql_* functions are **officially deprecated** (as of PHP 5.5. It's likely to be removed in the next major release)

See here [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: `MYSQL_NUM` was the solution. Thank you!